# Apply Zscore after groupby in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scipy, statistics

I am trying to apply a function on a grouped dataset. For that I have this Pandas dataframe:

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('aabdee'),
        'AA':['2020-03-22', '2020-03-22', '2020-03-29', '2020-03-22','2020-03-22', '2020-03-29'],
         'B':[1,0.5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[1,3,1,7,1,1],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4]
})
```

And I want to apply a Zscore to each column (grouped by the variables A and AA). So I did:

```
numeric_columns = test_df.select_dtypes(np.number)
test_df.groupby(['A', 'AA'])[numeric_columns.columns].apply(stats.zscore)
```

But then I have lot of errors, like this:

```
Series.name must be a hashable type
```

and this:

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  return (a - mns) / sstd
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me working [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
numeric_columns = test_df.select_dtypes(np.number)

c = numeric_columns.columns
test_df[c] = test_df.groupby(['A', 'AA'])[c].transform(stats.zscore)

print (test_df)
   A          AA    B    C    D    E
0  a  2020-03-22  1.0 -1.0 -1.0  1.0
1  a  2020-03-22 -1.0  1.0  1.0 -1.0
2  b  2020-03-29  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  d  2020-03-22  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  e  2020-03-22  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
5  e  2020-03-29  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

EDIT:

```
c = numeric_columns.columns
for g, df in  test_df.groupby(['A', 'AA']):
    print (df)

   A          AA    B  C  D  E
0  a  2020-03-22  1.0  7  1  5
1  a  2020-03-22  0.5  8  3  3
   A          AA    B  C  D  E
2  b  2020-03-29  4.0  9  1  6
   A          AA    B  C  D  E
3  d  2020-03-22  5.0  4  7  9
   A          AA    B  C  D  E
4  e  2020-03-22  5.0  2  1  2
   A          AA    B  C  D  E
5  e  2020-03-29  4.0  3  1  4
```

Comment: Well, I don't think it worked since there is a lot of NaN. Why you think this is right?

Comment: Z score is == (number - mean/standar deviation). And I wanted this on every one of the groups, it should not be an output NaN as far as I can see

Comment: @CatarinaNogueira - Output is expected, because here is used `groupby`. So function is apply for each group separately. And because only first group has 2 rows, all another groups has only 1 row, std of one line is `NaN`, so output is `NaN` of zscore.

Comment: even but for example, if you have two groups with more than one observation on the week 2020-03-22,  just the first group will be taken into account. The other group (of the week 2020-03-29)  will be NA, instead of being applied Zscore on it too

Comment: @CatarinaNogueira - Yes, exaclty. Because all another groups has length `1`, but first group has length `2`

Comment: Wait, if I just group with the "AA' this happens too. If you check on column 'b', the week 2020-03-22 has 4 observations and the week 2020-03-29 has 2, so they should be grouped, but all observations from the week  2020-03-29  on column B have NaA

Comment: @CatarinaNogueira - Give me a sec.

Comment: @CatarinaNogueira - If groups by 2 columns, it grouping by their combinations, answer was edited for see groups.

Comment: In your answer edited you are not applying Zscore, I got confused

Comment: @CatarinaNogueira - It is only for expalin how looks groups ;)

Comment: Ahh ok! I just still don't get it then. If we group just by 'AA', then we have two groups with more than one observation on it, as I could see using your code to check the groups. But even this way the answer is NaN for one of the groups.

Comment: @CatarinaNogueira - It seems not understand each other. `EDIT` part of answer explain reason of missing values - because one row groups for each groups exclude first one.

Comment: Yes, this I got, but if you have two groups with two rows and run your same code of your original answer I got NaN values still

Comment: @CatarinaNogueira - hmmm, it is weird, is possible see data for verify it?

Comment: Sure! It's the same data of my question, the change is on the grouping, it become like this, just with the 'AA' column: test_df[c] = test_df.groupby(['AA'])[c].transform(stats.zscore)

Comment: @CatarinaNogueira - tested and reaso is `4,4` and `1,1` values per group only, same values in column per group.

Comment: Wait, so you have done this below and got no NaN, is that? 
numeric_columns = test_df.select_dtypes(np.number)
c = numeric_columns.columns
test_df[c] = test_df.groupby(['AA'])[c].transform(stats.zscore)
print(test_df)

Comment: I got `NaN`s, but only for `B, D` columns for group `2020-03-29`

Comment: Yes, but B and D have the same date, so they are a two row group. You told me that one row group get excluded, but this is a two row group... So i don't get this

Comment: @CatarinaNogueira - Yes, there are `NaN`s with 2 reasons - length is 1 or same values per group, like `B,D` is only `1` and `4` per `2020-03-29`

Comment: B,D is not a two length group when I group just for weeks? They are in the same week...

Comment: yes, but there is `1,1` and `4,4` values, so ot is second possible reason for `NaN`.